# PostgreSQL 9.3: convert column to row

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, postgresql-9.3

I would like to create a view from a table like this :

Example in table :

```
cola      column1        
-------------------
D1        val1, val2
D3        val3
```

Expected Result into a view:

```
cola      column1        
-------------------
D1        val1
D1        val2
D3        val3
```

I want to divide the value of column1 and create a new row, but keep the values of the other columns.

Comment: You could set up three queries (single values, left value, right value) and combine them with a `UNION`. Or maybe look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns].

Answer (score 2):

just agg to array and unnest it:

```
t=# with c(cola,c1) as (values('d1','v1,v2'),('d2','v3'))
select cola,unnest(string_to_array(c1,',')) column1 from c;
 cola | column1
------+---------
 d1   | v1
 d1   | v2
 d2   | v3
(3 rows)
```

from :

```
t=# with c(cola,c1) as (values('d1','v1,v2'),('d2','v3'))
select * from c;
 cola |  c1
------+-------
 d1   | v1,v2
 d2   | v3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect :)